# Create subfolders and move files to new subfolders

Tags: vba, subdirectory

Create subfolders and move files to new subfolders

I am trying to adapt the code from [Loop Through All Folders and All its Subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740784/loop-through-all-folders-and-all-its-subfolders-vba) marked as solved to:

- create a 2020 subfolder in a series of subfolders
- move all files within the existing subfolder to the new 2020 subfolder

However the code gives a `Path not found` error. `MoveFile` is also giving a `Path not found` error.

Could someone please point out the fault in the code?

```
Sub Create_subfolders_move_files()

Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object

FromPath = "C:\Users\xyz\"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(FromPath)

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files

            FileInFolder.Move (objSubFolder.path & "\2020\")

    Next FileInFolder
    
Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder *"C:\Users\xyz"* doesn't exist so you cannot refer to it by using `Fso.GetFolder` method (it can be used only for existing folders).

First, you have to create it and you can do it by using method `Fso.CreateFolder`. However, this method doesn't work if you want to add nested folders, i.e.:

- if the folder *"C:\Users"* already exists you can create folder *"C:\Users\xyz"*
- you won't be able to create folder *"C:\Users\xyz\abc"* directly. It will throw the same error - *Path not found*. In order to create folder *"C:\Users\xyz\abc"*, first you would have to create folder *"C:\Users\xyz"*:

```
    Call fso.CreateFolder("C:\Users\xyz")
    Call fso.CreateFolder("C:\Users\xyz\abc")
```

As you can guess, this is not a good practice to hard-coding things like that, better approach is to create a generic function that works recursively and create all the folders no matter how many levels it requires. I have already created such function, as it happens, and you are free to use it:
http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/system/createFolder.php

Comment: Hi @mielk - the folders already exist `C:\Users\xyz` and >50 subfolders  `C:\Users\xyz\abc`. The objective is to create a 2020 subfolder each of the existing >50 folders, e.g. `C:\Users\xyz\abc\2020\.` I do not see how I can use the code you link to because I do not need to create folders and also your `folderPath` is a string.